# What constitutes semantic analysis apart from type checking?

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, semantic-analysis, compile-time-type-checking

I am writing a compiler from Java 1.0 to x86. I have built the Abstract Syntax Tree (using lex + yacc) and the symbol table. Now, in order to do semantic analysis I plan on traversing the AST in a Depth-first order , type-checking each syntactic construct as I reach its node while also performing necessary type conversions. However, before proceeding to intermediate code generation, what more should be done in the semantic analysis phase.

Comment: It's up to you, really. Typical checks would include checks for missing or duplicate identifiers, range checks that can be performed at compile-time (arrays, constant assignment, and so on). This can also include live variable analysis (i.e. is a variable referenced before it's initialized, and so on), but this is not strictly required, just a nice-to-have.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError People have said that scope analysis is a part of semantic analysis. But since scope analysis I believe involves creation of global and local scopes and linking these scopes together to form a tree structure, I think it can be done while generating the syntax tree itself and it is not a part of semantic analysis since we are not doing anything meaning related here.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  Also, what do you mean by missing or duplicate identifiers?

Comment: Identifiers that are either not defined at all or defined twice in the same scope.

Comment: I don't know that there is a limit to what constitutes semantic analysis, but constant folding, elimination of redundant evaluation of common subexpressions and dead code elimination are pretty common. There are also a lot of analyses based on control flow analysis and symbolic execution.